# How to add homepage Widget?

Tags: plugins, php, widgets

How do I add a 'Homepage' widget to my widget bar in Wordpress 3.3 ??!!

**EG:** Dashboard > Widgets > Homepage with same fields as others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had good luck with the [Widget Logic plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/).  It lets you use template-style logic for each widget.  It's not quite the same as adding a whole new admin page just for conditional widgets (you would need to create and register a new sidebar, etc), but it's great for the quick-and-dirty 'get it in there now' needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Looks like a cool plugin, but I'm having trouble using it. After I've activated it what can I do to mimic a 'Homepage' widget? I just see two radio options that have appeared under the widgets screen; "widget_content' filter Use 'wp_reset_query' fix" - toggling either hasn't shown to do anything?

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick;

**Widget on Pages Plugin.**

http://gingerbreaddesign.co.uk/wordpress/widgets-on-pages/

Comment: If your own answer helped, then accept it to improve your acceptance rate.